# Setting queryTimeout Value of Datasource created via JNDI

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

I have following definition to get datasource object  via JNDI created at weblogic 12c 
application server.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="test.db" jndi-name="DB_JNDI"/>

<bean name="TestImpl" class="com.test.db.TestImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="test.db" />
</bean>
```

I would like to know how I can set queryTimeOut value of datasource and how I can pass this value while initializing it

Using weblogic 12c, Spring 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a `init()` method  then changed the bean definition as follow. Everything is working fine.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="test.db" jndi-name="DB_JNDI"/>

<bean name="TestImpl" class="com.test.db.TestImpl" init-method="init">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="test.db" />
    <property name="queryTimeout" value="${prop.querytimeout}" />
</bean>
```

**TestImpl.java**

```
   public void init() {
        getJdbcTemplate().setQueryTimeout(queryTimeout);
   }
```